# How to hide my profile from search in Skype?

Tags: skype

I'd like to hide my contact from search in Skype. I mean if anyone search for me using my contact or name, will not be able to find me.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but you can email the Skype team

Answer (score 1):

You can do that Under [Profile](https://secure.skype.com/portal/profile). Scroll to **Profile Settings** and uncheck **Appear in search results and suggestions**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to completely remove being able to be found from Skype, but you can get very close by editing your profile and removing all identifying information.

You can edit your profile from the Skype window by clicking Skype > Profile > Edit Your Pofile

OR

1. Open your web browser and go to the Skype log-in page
2. Sign into your account
3. Click on Profile details under your Skype name in the middle left
   side of the window and edit all your profile details so that no
   personal information remains except your Registered e-mail address
   under Email settings.